# Question about Thomas-Fermi model

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body

The Thomas-Fermi model is based on the following proposition:

> every cell in the phase space of volume $h^3$ may host up to 2 electrons with opposite spin directions.
>   (here $h$ is the Planck constant.)

But how can this be justified?

Comment: You have learned that this minimal cell of phase space supplants a phase-space point, in QM, as no finer granularity is meaningful, right? How do you apply the Pauli exclusion principle?

Comment: Thanks @CosmasZachos. I understand the part related to the Pauli exclusion principle. But maybe since I haven't studied quantum statistical mechanics, I don't exactly understand why this granularity happens and why each cell's volume equals $h^3$. However I guess that this can be related to the uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider a quantum particle confined in a volume $V$, the energy states allowed must satisfy Schrodinger equation:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\Psi=E\Psi$$

The wave function must vanish at the boundary of the volume, this means that the total number of spatial orbital is (closely) equal to the volume of an octant of a sphere of radius $n=(n_{x}^2+n_{y}^2+n_{z}^2)^{1/2}$, where $n_{x},n_{y},n_{z}$ are positive integers related to the energy of the particle

$$n_{x}^2+n_{y}^2+n_{z}^2=\frac{2mEV^{2/3}}{\pi^2 \hbar^2}$$

Now, the volume of the octant gives the number $N_{states}$ of individual particle states allowed and if we consider the spin degeneracy of the electron using a factor 2 we get

$$N_{states}=2\frac{1}{8}\frac{4\pi}{3}n^3$$

Now we can replace $n^3$ with an expression containing $E$ and with a little algebra we obtain

$$N_{states}=\frac{V}{h^3}\frac{8\pi}{3}(2mE)^{3/2}=\frac{V}{h^3}\frac{8\pi}{3}P^{3}$$

from this formula we can clearly see that $h^3$ represents the volume of a cell in the phase space as you can get the same number by integrating on the phase space and multiplying by 2:

$$N_{states}\simeq \frac{2}{h^3}\int\int_{p\le P_{max}}d^3qd^3p$$

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. But it is derived for the case when there is no potential energy. So, now the question is: Is there a more general proof?, or the TF model is using this just as an approximation?